# DockerCompose + Hostname

Tags: .net-core, docker-compose

Hi I'm am creating 3 webApi's a GateWay and I'm using docker in visualStudio0217 (.netCore).

The projects compile fine and I see the images were created.
[image]

But whe I try to go to the Url's http://LocalHost:9002 or http://LocalHost:9000 these dont work

I have this docker compose:

[image]

Do I need to do something else?

Comment: Please share your Dockerfile's

Answer (score 1):

```
instead of http://LocalHost:9002   use  http://localhost:57978
instead of http://LocalHost:9000   use  http://localhost:46429
```

Explanation

0.0.0.0:57978->8041/tcp means that host port 57978 is mapped to container port 8041

0.0.0.0:46429->8043/tcp means that host port 46429 is mapped to container port 8043

You can use this command to inspect your connections

```
docker inspect container_name
```

Comment: I tried with: "http://localhost:57978" but not works. I'm goign to check the detail using the command docker inspect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to add the "ports" in your docker-compose for each service.
Example:

ports:
       - "9002:80"